# Paypal Sandbox API No Transaction

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I'm trying to test my payment script with PayPal. It used to work 2 days ago but now, When I try to pay with one sandbox account to another, there is no transaction history between them. However, I'm getting redirected to success page URL saying that the transaction was successful after paying with the test account.

This was working 2 days ago and now it suddenly stopped showing transactions. There is no transaction history and so no IPN being issued by the PayPal. Is there a problem in their end or something wrong in my end ?

Comment: So you mean you are not able to see that transactions in your paypal test account?

Comment: No transaction is happening and so no transaction history is shown.

Comment: In paypal account..?

Comment: In sandbox PayPal account

Comment: Are you checking in merchant account or buyer account?

Comment: Checking the merchant account. But no transaction history in both accounts.

Comment: Could you please share your testing paypal details if possible?

Comment: I'm not sure if I am allowed to post them here in public. Does the transactions work between your test accounts ?

Comment: ya sure it will work

Comment: Sandbox has been having issues for about 24 hours. Before I went to sleep about 10 hours ago it was unusable. I have just woken up and it is still throwing random stuff out. You are just going to have to wait while paypal sorts it out.